# Nuxt.js SSR on changed sections, not entire pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Is it possible with Nuxt.js to do server side rendering on small changes within a page (which are reflected by the url) without the need for an entire page.

For instance, imagine I have a shop with sub categories and subcategories.
Subcategories contain products.

- Category 1

  - Subcat 1

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
  - Subcat 2

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
    - Product 3
  - Subcat 3

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
- Category 2

  - Subcat 1

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
  - Subcat 2

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
  - Subcat 3

    - Product 1
    - Product 2

I want to use smooth animations (fading and moving in) when someone opens a category and the subcategories are shown. At the same time, this should be reflected in the url for SEO purposes (/products/category1/subcategory3)
Implementing a page for this behavior seems like an overkill to me and makes my application unnecessary hard to maintain, but I can't figure out if what I'm trying to accomplish here is even possible with Nuxt.

Comment: Not quite follow how you suppose it to work. If its url that should be accessible and rendered by seo - then it should be fully rendered by nuxt.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but the answer I was expecting ;). How would one take care of async loading/updating components, changing the url when doing so, and rendering it serverside as well? I ask this mostly because we do some smooth transitions on the page when getting products from a different category on screen, the entire "page refresh" makes it impossible for us to achieve this...

Comment: Not quite understand. SSR happens on first load . When u navigate withing app it will be client and you can have any tranisition you want to

Comment: Yeah, but url changes need "Pages" in nuxt, which, on their turn, re-render the entire page right? So, for instance, if I go from /categories/chairs to categories/tables I can't animate the part of the page where the categories are shown... It re-renders the entire page...

Comment: You can. See nuxt-child component

Comment: Thanks Aldarund, will look into that and update my question when everything is rolling... Found that the asyncData() is also part of the solution...